# Problems with MySQL Workbench Dark Theme (White background with text)

Tags: mysql-workbench

I followed Gaston's tutorial here by pasting his commandds under the  tag. But on Windows 10 on the latest version of Workbench 8.0, I get white background around my texts. It looks ugly:
[image]

How can I fix this issue? I'm so used to dark theme editors. WHite background is too harsh for my eyes

You can see my editted XML and color options:
[image]

[image]

[image]